# Wordpress - page as category

Tags: wordpress, categories

I researched several tutorials and nothing ...

can someone tell me how do I print only the category "news" in the article page?

Theme Onepress*

```
<main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                    <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
                    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                        <?php

                            /*
                             * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                             * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                             * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                             */
                            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'list' );
                        ?>

                    <?php endwhile; ?>

                    <?php the_posts_navigation(); ?>

                <?php else : ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' ); ?>



<?php endif; ?>
                </main><!-- #main -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the easiest way is to create your own query:

```
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => array( 'news' ),
    'post_status'            => array( 'publish' ),
    'posts_per_page'         => '-1',
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        // do something
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

This gives you all the query results that are: published and of the 'news' custom post type.

```
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'post_status'            => array( 'publish' ),
    'category_name'          => 'news',
    'posts_per_page'         => '-1',
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        // do something
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

The second one gives you all the query results, that are published and in the category 'news'.